# Host multiple plumber API on shiny-server

Tags: shiny-server, plumber

I have shiny-server installed on my server and I want to run multiple plumber APIs from it. I have also R studio server, but with it I can run only 1 at the same time.

Do you know a method to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible to run Plumber API's with shiny-server (and [this ticket](https://github.com/trestletech/plumber/issues/240) seems to confirm that.

You can however run multiple Plumber API's using [RStudio Connect](https://www.rstudio.com/products/connect/), and even scale the resources you allocate to your plumber API up or down depending on the need.

Given that RStudio Connect is a commercial product, it may not be a deplyment option for your (at this moment). You can, however, still host multiple Plumber API's on your server, but using Docker. The instructions are [included in the Plumber documentation](https://www.rplumber.io/docs/hosting.html#docker).